# How can I insert empty lines into my org-mode agenda?

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I am using org-mode to organize my tasks. I use standard priorities.

Is it possible to insert empty lines into the standard agenda view? I have many tasks per day, and usually sort them by priority. The #A are shown on top, #B in the middle, #C at the bottom.

I would like to have an empty line as a separator after each priority class (one empty line after all the #A tasks, one empty line after all #B tasks, one empty line after the #C tasks). This would make my agenda much more readable.

I do find help about how to insert dividers after blocks, but I do not use blocks.

Thank you!

Comment: Although the following link is far beyond what most people will ever use, it is a method of creating a custom agenda view for those items normally created with the `org-agenda-list` function.  It is possible to examine the text-properties of the data that is gathered and then alter one or more elements of the list and/or insert new lines (based on select criteria) into the buffer as it is being populated.  http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/12563/2287  I have been using a custom agenda view for the past couple of years and have grown quite fond of it.

Comment: Another option would be to use something like the `org-agenda-mode-hook` and alter the data in the *stock/regular/normal* agenda buffer (with a custom function) at the tail end of the population process.  Let's say for example that the buffer is sorted so that groups of priorities are together -- the custom function can search for the first priority of the group and insert a `\n` before the first heading in that group.

Comment: @manetsus Yes, I googled it and searched at stackexchange and other places.

Comment: @lawlist Thank you for the comments! I believe it is possible to insert lines if I do major changes and write my own code. But I would not want to do this right now. I am currently using an iOs app for my tasks (easier to use, much less powerful) and I am currently switching to org-mode. It is already a quite steep learning curve :-)  ...

Comment: Here is a simple example of how to modify the agenda buffer at the tail end of the creation process using the `org-agenda-finalize-hook` -- just add the snippet to the `.emacs` file, save and restart Emacs.  `(require 'org-agenda) (defun my-custom-agenda-fn () (save-excursion (goto-char (point-min)) (dolist (priority '("\\[#A\\]" "\\[#B\\]" "\\[#C\\]" "\\[#D\\]" "\\[#E\\]")) (when (re-search-forward priority nil t) (goto-char (point-at-bol)) (insert "\n"))))) (add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook 'my-custom-agenda-fn)`

Comment: Wow! This is extremely helpful. Some minor changes are required: this code seems to add \n _before_ the first occurence of [#A],[#B],[#C], but not after its last occurence. Would this also be possible? Currently, if I use your code, there is no newline between the #C tasks and the habits (the habits are shown below all tasks).

Comment: If you wouldn't mind editing your question to include *detailed* examples of **before** and proposed **after**, then I'd be happy to take a stab at an answer later on in the day.  Please use just text in your *detailed* examples so that I can block/copy the test data without retyping everything based on an image/picture.  You can create a verbatim block in your question by placing at least four (4) spaces at the beginning of each line.

Comment: I understand that my question is not specific enough; but: I have figured out how to adapt your code so that it fits my needs. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: If you'd like to post an answer after you get everything working, then that will show this question as having been resolved -- I believe the waiting period is something like 36 to 48 hours (after posting the question) before you can accept your own answer, so you can check back later on in the week to place a check-mark next to your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working solution from the code @lawlist provided in the comments. It will visually delimit the current day's tasks based on priority

```
  (defun my-custom-agenda-fn ()
    (save-excursion
     (let ((delimit "------------------------"))
      (org-agenda-goto-today)
      (dolist
          (priority '("\\[#A\\]" "\\[#B\\]" "\\[#C\\]" "\\[#D\\]" "\\[#E\\]"))
        (when (re-search-forward priority nil t)
          (goto-char (point-at-bol)) (insert (concat delimit "\n"))))
      (org-agenda-goto-today)
      (when (re-search-forward delimit nil t)
        (delete-region
         (progn (forward-visible-line 0) (point))
         (progn (forward-visible-line 1) (point))))
      ))
   )

(add-hook 'org-agenda-finalize-hook 'my-custom-agenda-fn)
```